Error - Argument passed to call that takes no arguments
I am struggling to figure out the following error that appears twice in this file:
Argument passed to call that takes no arguments
Argument passed to call that takes no arguments
Please help! This should allow the user to login based on the user type. I will post the code below here.
struct PoppyApp: App {
    @StateObject private var session = Session()
    @StateObject private var eventManager: EventManager

    init() {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        let userId = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid ?? ""
        _eventManager = StateObject(wrappedValue: 

EventManager(userId: userId))
        }
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(session)
                .environmentObject(eventManager)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var session: Session

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            if session.isAuthenticated {
                authenticatedView
            } else {
                LoginView().environmentObject(session)
            }
        }
    }

    @ViewBuilder
    private var authenticatedView: some View {
        switch session.userType {
        case .vendor:
            VendorHomeView().environmentObject(session)
        case .eventOrganizer:
            OrganizerHomePage(userId: session.userId ?? "").environmentObject(session)
        default:
            Text("Unsupported user type")
        }
    }


    @ViewBuilder
    private func viewForUserType(using userId: String) -> some View {
        switch session.userType {
        case .vendor:
            VendorHomeView().environmentObject(session)  // Correct if no args needed
        case .eventOrganizer:
            OrganizerHomePage(userId: userId).environmentObject(session)  // Ensure userId is required
        default:
            FirstView().environmentObject(session)
        }
    }

    private var errorView: some View {
        Text("An error occurred. Please try logging in again.")
    }
}


If you don't clarify what lines specifically are leading to the error, we're going to struggle to figure it out too.

here are the lines the two errors are related to (authenticatedView and viewForUserType):
OrganizerHomePage(userId: session.userId ?? "").environmentObject(session)
OrganizerHomePage(userId: userId).environmentObject(session)  // Ensure userId is required

OK. So the error is "argument passed to call that takes no arguments" and occurring on lines with OrganizerHomePage(userId: ...) ... so ... does OrganizerHomePage have a constructor that takes an argument ... ?
